# Is there a "file-like" serial port interface in Java8 under Windows (recent, 7 or 8)

Tags: java, serial-port, ftdi

I'm using the following code under Java8 for MacOS X:

```
new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/dev/cu.usbserial-A601EQIH"))
    .lines()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Provided:

- there is a VCP driver from FTDI installed
- there is an FTDI usb-serial device plugged-in and sending data to computer, line by line

Then:

- this code will iterate the lines sent and print them on the console.

Is there such a `"/dev/cu.usbserial-A601EQIH"` file on Windows, provided we install the right virtual com port drivers? I have no windows machine to try it, and would like to answer that question before I show off that code at a conference...

PS: As is implied by code, I do not want to use any library apart standard Java8 libraries.

Comment: Since you are using Java 8, why go through a `BufferedReader` at all? Just use [`Files.lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

Comment: Because I hate Path? Because FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("dev", "cu.usbserial-A601EQIH"); sounds unnatural? Much likely because I got used to that way and didn't switch to the other...

Comment: `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath()` is equivalent to `Paths.get()`. You may "hate" it but it is miles better than `File`.